# Change scale of percentage to a negative to positive scale?

Tags: calculus

I've been checking out a few answers ([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330381/calculate-percentage-on-negative-to-positive-scale) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1680543/how-do-i-convert-a-percentage-from-a-1-100-scale-to-a-different-scale)) but I cannot come up with the result on my own.

Here is my problem:

I have a value from 0 to 100 that I need to express on a scale from -40 to 40.

Can someone please direct me to a proper formula?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=line+through+(0,-40),+(100,40) might help you. Scroll down a bit to see useful formulae.

Comment: thank you, that indeed helped a lot. val = (4*x)/5 - 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want toe formula for the straight line going through the points $(x_1,y_1)=(0,-40)$ and $(x_2,y_2)=(100,40)$. The formula for this is $$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$$ where $$m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$

So in your example, this gives $$m=\frac{80}{100}=0.8\\y+40=0.8x\\y=0.8x-40$$Here, $x$ is your "percentage" value, and $y$ gives you the corresponding value on the scale from $-40$ to $40$.

Comment: Thanks, the first comment actually helped me coming to this conclusion but I will mark this as accepted answer to close this question. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat different way of looking at it.  You want to change from a scale that has a range of $100$ to a scale that has a range of $80$, so multiply by $.8$.  Then you want to move the origin of the scale from $0$ to $-40$, so subtract $40$.  This gives $$y=.8x-40.$$

This works so simply because the original origin is $0$ and it doesn't change when you multiply by $.8.$  If the original scale ran from $20$ to $120$, we would still multiply by $.8$, but now the origin would have moved to $16$, so we would subtract $56$, not $60.$

Comment: Thank you for this alternate answer